# ZF 1.12 custom view helper - failed opening

Tags: php, zend-framework, view-helpers

I'm working on restructuring my Zend 1.12 project. I have a couple of view helpers:

- OutputComplexForm.php
- OutputDistributorsList.php

I put them in /application/views/helpers

Class names are

- Zend_View_Helper_OutputComplexForm
- Zend_View_Helper_OutputDistributorsList

As I understand if you have Zend_View_Helper prefix you don't need to add any configs to application.ini

Now, when I try to load any page (even those which don't use helpers) I receive error:

```
Message: Zend_Session::start() - /otms/vendor/zendframework/zendframework1/library/Zend/Loader.php(Line:134): Error #2 include_once(): Failed opening    'Zend/View/Helper/OutputComplexForm.php' for inclusion (include_path='/otms/application/../library:/otms/application/../library/phpseclib0.3.1:/otms/application/../library/Amazon:/otms/application/../library/USPS:/otms/application/../library/Composer:/otms/library:/otms/vendor/phpseclib/phpseclib/phpseclib:/otms/vendor/zendframework/zendframework1/library:.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear')
```

Did I miss something?

### UPD

I've found out that error occurred after calling function

```
$startedCleanly = session_start(); //line 482
```

in file /Zend/Session.php. After this call property Zend_Session_Exception::$sessionStartError contains described error message. I still don't see connection between starting session and initialising view helper.

Answer (score 0):

For application-specific classes that you write - stuff that appears inside `./application/*` - should typically not be in the `Zend_` pseudo-namespace. Rather, they should be in the `appnamespace`, as configured in `./application/config/application.ini`.

The default namespace is 'Application_', so a view-helper called `MyHelper` would typically be stored in the file `./application/views/helpers/MyHelper.php`:

```
class Application_View_Helper_MyHelper extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract
{
    public function myHelper()
    {
        // do your stuff here
    }
}
```

Note that the class name is upper-camel-case `MyHelper` and the method is lower-camelcase `myHelper()`.

In your view, you can invoke your view-helper with:

```
<?php

$output = $this->myHelper();
// Do something with $output
```

With these conventions on namespace, class name, and file location/name, and invocation syntax, the View's plugin loader should be able find, load, and execute your view-helper method.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I changed class name to "Application_View_Helper_OutputComplexForm" and in application.ini I have line "appnamespace = "Application"". However I got message: "Plugin by name 'OutputComplexForm' was not found in the registry; used paths:
Zend_View_Helper_: Zend/View/Helper/:/otms/application/views/helpers/".

Comment: Just checking: Is the method signature/name in the class as follows: `public function outputComplexForm()` The case of the classname, the filename, and the method name need to be just so.